# How can I reload and re-enter a modified Racket file in Geiser?

Tags: emacs, scheme, racket, geiser

I'm using Geiser in Emacs on Windows as a Racket programming environment. I'm working on the file `"d:/code/racket/foo.rkt"`. `"d:/code/racket/foo.rkt"` is a module (it starts with `#lang racket)`.

I can use `,enter "d:/code/racket/foo.rkt"` at the Racket REPL to enter the module, and having done so I can successfully execute functions from the file.

However, if I change the file and re-run `,enter "d:/code/racket/foo.rkt"`, the file is not re-loaded: changes to functions in my file are not reflected when I re-execute them in the REPL.

I have tried re-compiling my buffer with `C-c C-k` before re-running `,enter`, but this makes no difference.
I've also tried executing `,enter #f` to exit the `foo.rkt` module, then re-running `,enter "d:/code/racket/foo.rkt"`; this still doesn't reload the module.

I've also observed that running `(enter! (file "d:/code/racket/foo.rkt"))` instead of `,enter "d:/code/racket/foo.rkt"` *does* reload the file.

Is this a known limitation of Geiser's `,enter` form, or am I missing a trick?

---

(Versions are: Geiser 0.5, Emacs 24.3.1, Racket 6.0, Windows 8)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. It works on my machine (Mac OSX).
There is also the command to switch to the repl and eval the module (C-c C-a)
It even reloads the definition if I only do a "Eval definition and go"

Comment: This is happening to me as well on arch linux.  As a workaround, using [racket-mode](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode), `racket-run` will accordingly re-run the module.